# Python list assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

How can this be explained?

```
 s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 s[0] = s[0:0]                    #replace s[0] by empty list s[0:0]
 s
 [[], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]     # s after assignment
 len(s)
 9

 s[3] = s[0:0]                    # samething for s[3]
 [[], 2, 3, [], 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]    # s after s[3] has been replaced by s[0:0]
 len(s)
 9

 s[5:7] = s[0:0]                  # replace a slice by empty list
 s
 [[], 2, 3, [], 5, 8, 9]          # slice has been removed
 len(s)
 7
```

By following the logic from the first part where the element is replaced by an empty list and the length of the list is conserved, I can expect that each element of the slice should be replaced by an empty list.

Well, it is not! How is it explained?

Comment: "I can expect that each element of the slice should be replaced by an empty list" - slice assignment doesn't operate elementwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a single element of the list on the left-hand side, you replace that single element with whatever's on the right-hand side.

When you have a *slice* on the left-hand side, you replace all the elements of that slice with the elements of the list on the right-hand side. If you didn't have a list or other kind of iterable on the right side, the assignment would fail. Since the list on the right-hand side was empty, you ended up deleting the elements.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that the length of the list is always conserved.  What is true is that the slice on the left is replaced with whatever is found on the right.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print(lst[0]) # prints one value
print(lst[3]) # prints one value
print(len(lst[1:3])) # prints 2, length of sublist
print(len(lst[:])) # prints 4, length of whole list

lst[:] = []  # replace entire list with empty list
```

By the way it is very weird to use the slice `[0:0]` to get a zero-length list.  Easier to understand if the code just put `[]`, the literal that represents a zero-length list.

Comment: True! It is more of a theoretical question rather than practical.

Answer (score 2):

```
s[3] = s[0:0]   # replacing single element
s[5:7] = s[0:0] # replacing two elements and setting to []  removes the elements.
using s[5] = s[0:0],s[6] = s[0:0] is different from s[5:7]
```

If you change `s[5:7] = s[0:0]`  to `s[5:7] = s[0:2]`, you will get different behaviour, both will be changed.

If you use  `s[5:7] = s[0:1]`the element at index 5 will be changed and the element at index 6 will be removed.

Comment: Hi Padraic! For sure, it replaces 2 elements. But why are not those two elements empty lists?

Comment: you are basically turning two elements into one.

Comment: OK, and where is that one element?

Comment: @flamenco, you are basically turning two elements into None not one.